# Two 3-way switches from one source

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, multiway-switch

I have two light fixtures that I'd like to have on separate 3-way switches. Can I do that from one power source? Can I split/daisy chain the power source and 'travel' them to each light fixture and then to both light switches? Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: There are 6 ways to wire a 3-way setup. Do you *need* to take power to the lights first, and then have the switches be spurs? Can power come to a switch box?  Also, any possibility of putting conduit e.g. "smurf tube" flex plastic between the switch boxes?

Comment: Taking power to the lights first would make running the wires easier and also use less material. I can take it to the switches first, if necessary. I wasn't thinking of using conduit or smurf tube since I'm running the wires through insulation in the attic.

Comment: Are you OK with replacing the wiring in the walls?

Comment: @Daniel OK how about smurf tube between lamp and switches *and also* between switches and other switches?  I assume it 2 switches in each of 2 locations.  While I know the smurf sounds like "more material", it's actually *less* material since you can common things that are common like always-hot and ground, and you can omit neutral since it can easily be added later.  Can't do that in cables.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica please sum that in a answer, since the other answer is scaring me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. But be prepared to run some serious cables or wires in conduit.

The basic problem is you need neutral in each switch box. That really complicates things because a 3-wire cable doesn't have enough wires for that, depending on how the circuit is configured.

Some options:

- Panel -> Light -> Switch 1 -> Switch 2 (this sounds closest to OP's description)

  - Panel -> Light = /2 hot/neutral
  - Light -> Switch 1 = /3 hot/neutral/switched hot
  - Switch 1 -> Switch 2 = /4 hot/neutral/traveler 1/traveler 2
- Panel -> Switch 1 -> Switch 2 -> Light

  - Panel -> Switch 1 = /2 hot/neutral
  - Switch 1 -> Switch 2 = /3 traveler 1/traveler 2/neutral
  - Switch 2 -> Light = /2 switched hot/neutral
- Panel -> Switch 1 -> Switch 2 *and* Switch 1 -> Light

  - Panel -> Switch 1 = /2 hot/neutral
  - Switch 1 -> Switch 2 = /4 traveler 1/traveler 2/neutral/switched hot
  - Switch 1 -> Light = /2 switched hot/neutral

and I think there are some more possibilities. But you get the idea: Only by very careful planning can you avoid needing /4 cable.

If you have (or can add) conduit then things are much easier because running 4 wires (or 5 including ground) with conduit is not a big deal.

Neutral is always white (or gray), and in most new installations (main exception: 240V-only circuits), white will always be neutral. There used to be big exceptions for 3-way circuits and for switch loops, but neither of those apply in new circuits because you have to have neutral.

Note that one way to simplify things is, ironically, to use smart switches. It is a bit ironic because smart switches are one of the big reasons that neutral is required! But for 3-way switches they can save a lot of headaches, as you can generally run either /2 or /3 everywhere and not need to go to /4. That's because smart switches can either communicate with a single wire (instead of two separate travelers) or wirelessly.